# Null Propagation - Second null checking

Tags: c#, null-propagation-operator

I want to insert another null checking on the theme.VersionStamp. Is there a way that I can insert it inside the SequenceEqual argument?

```
if (theme.VersionStamp != null)
{ 
    if (!origTheme?.VersionStamp.SequenceEqual(theme.VersionStamp) ?? false)
    {
        throw new TwConcurrencyException();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I want to insert another null checking on the theme"_ -- why? by the time you get to that part of the code, you already know the value is not `null`. What's the point of a null check there? If there is a point, what kind of null check do you want? What do you want the outcome to be? Fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] showing clearly what you're doing, explain what that code does and exactly what it is you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not required right since anyways you are making that null check `if (theme.VersionStamp != null){` and then proceeding. But you could still check again and pass-in a default argument like

```
if (!origTheme?.VersionStamp.SequenceEqual(theme.VersionStamp ?? new VersionStamp()) ?? false)
```

Also, I would extend your first `null` check to below

```
if (theme != null && theme.VersionStamp != null)
{
```

Comment: the "theme" always has a value. theme.versionstamp can be nullable though.

Comment: If `theme` can be null as well, the first check can be `if (theme?.VersionStamp != null)` which will encapsulate both.

Comment: So, I've checked with the original author of the code, turns out that he just missed out populating the version stamp of the object when a certain logic is hit that is why I'm getting instances of null version stamp. Anyway, thanks for the help, I've learned much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, adding a null check when passing an argument is not possible.

The shortest you can get would be:

```
if (theme?.VersionStamp == null || 
    !origTheme?.VersionStamp?.SequenceEqual(theme.VersionStamp) ?? false)
{
    throw new TwConcurrencyException();
}
```

I wouldn't pass an default argument like Rahul is doing, because if the `VersionStamp` of the `origTheme` is equal to a default `VersionStamp` `SequenceEqual` would incorrectly return `true`

Comment: With C# 7 and [Throw Expressions](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13389) this is now possible: `.SequenceEqual(theme.VersionStamp ?? throw new ArgumentException(...))` In **this** case, however, it unnecessary because of the former `if` statement.